# populate additional information of the 'through' table in sails

Tags: sails.js, populate

I have two models and there is many to many association in between them(I am using sails.js framework). I have added the addition field in the association table. I want to populate that addition field. How do I achieve this? My models are given below:

```
//Store.js file
module.exports = {
 autoCreatedAt: false,
 autoUpdatedAt: false,
 attributes: {
 name: "string",
 slug: "string",
 imageURL: "string",
 termsAndConditions: "string",
 link: "string",
 productID: {
 collection: 'product', //This is for association with the product model
 via: 'storeID',
 through: 'price'
 }
}
};
```

Below is my Product.js file

```
 //Product.js
 module.exports = {
 autoCreatedAt: false,
 autoUpdatedAt: false,
 attributes: {
 name: 'string',
 storeID: {
  collection: 'stores',
  via: 'productID',  //This is for association with the Store model
  through: 'price'
 }
 }
};
```

And below is my through model Price.js

```
 module.exports = {
 autoCreatedAt: false,
 autoUpdatedAt: false,
 attributes: {
  storeID: {
  model: 'stores'
 },
 productID: {
  model: 'product'
 },
 price: 'integer'  //I want to populate this additional field when calling api '/product' or '/store'
}
};
```

How to populate the additional field price of Price table from calling the api '/product'   or '/store'?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the callback function after populating (exec or then depending on your implementation) Find the record in the price table and perform update on that record to change the value of price from null to whatever value you want. Share your implementation code for more detailed answer.